# LineLegend is behaving erratically

Tags: legending

The top one is fine, but if I change Red into dashed version, it behaves erratically.

[image]

Comment: Use `Directive[Blue,Dashed]` instead of `{Blue, Dashed}`.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much! It seems that only changing one of it in your way is sufficient.

Comment: Since version 6, `Directive` should *always* be used instead of `{...}` when specifying a list of styles...  (like in legends, PlotStyle, etc.)  Lists are ambiguous and cause problems.

Comment: Thank you again for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 6):

I think the behavior of `LineLegend` exhibited in the question, if not a bug, is within an epsilon of a bug. Consider that the following all succeed ...

```
LineLegend[{{Red, Dashed}, Green, Blue}, {"r", "g", "b"}]

LineLegend[{{Red, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}, Blue}, {"r", "g", "b"}] 

LineLegend[{Directive[Red, Dashed], {Green, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}}, {"r", "g", "b"}]

LineLegend[{{Red, Dashed}, Directive[Green, Dashed], {Blue, Dashed}}, {"r", "g", "b"}]

LineLegend[{{Red, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, {"r", "g", "b"}]
```

... and that this is the only failure case.

```
LineLegend[{{Red, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}}, {"r", "g", "b"}]
```

The singleton nature of the failure strikes me as indicating there is some edge case that has been missed in the *Mathematica* code underlying the evaluation or internal use of the 1st argument of `LineLegend`.

Comment: It's an "internal" use to make it compatible with `ChartLegends`, see the output of `BarChart` with multiple data sets.

Comment: If not a bug, definitely a WTF